# Python read file and write lines according to their index number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this file `in.txt`, which assumingly has 100 lines. What I want to do is to read the file and then write to another file, lines according to their index. example:

```
1 10: library=digital library collection=digital library>en
2 10: information=digital library retrieval=digital library system=digital library>en
3 10: term=digital library digital=digital library>en
4 10: user=digital library experience=digital library>en
5 10: software=digital library developer=digit
```

I need to only write the 2nd and 5th line into the new file, `out.txt`

So say I have a function called `clean2` and then I want to write only specific lines (2nd and 5th) into the new file `out.txt`

```
input = open('/path/to/file/in.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('/path/to/file/out.txt', 'w')
for i,line in enumerate(input):
    line = clean2(line)
    #what goes here?
    outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `clean2` ?

Comment: can you add what you expect as output from the input you provided because it is not clear what you expect?

Comment: `clean2` is another function irrelevant to this question. the ouput should be a text file containing only the 2nd and 5th line. simple as that. the solution though needs to be generalized and easily applied to other lines as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that the 2nd line has index 1, the 5th has index 4.

```
for i,line in enumerate(input):
    line = clean2(line)
    if i in (1, 4):
        outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below,

```
input = open('/path/to/file/in.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('/path/to/file/out.txt', 'w')
for i,line in enumerate(input):
    if i == 1 or i == 4:
        outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
input.close()
```